# How do I add a url button to a subclass of view in Pycord?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I have a help command in my pycord bot that displays a list of commands. This is the embed to display:

```
helpEmbed = discord.Embed(title='BlazingBot Help', description='Hi, I\'m a bot made by BlazingLeaf#3982, but I can\'t do much yet because I\'m still under development')
```

This is the subclass of view (When the user clicks the Commands button, it switches to a different embed and view):

```
class helpView(View):
  @discord.ui.button(label='Commands', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
  async def command_callback(self, button, interaction):
    await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=commandEmbed, view=commandView())
```

Then I have the slash command:

```
@bot.slash_command(name='help', description='Show a list of commands and get a link to the support server!', guild_ids=[861826763570151424])
async def help(ctx):
  await ctx.interaction.response.send_message(embed=helpEmbed, view=helpView())
```

And this works fine, but I also want to add a URL button that leads to the support server for my bot. I checked the api and it mentions that you can't create a URL button with the @discord.ui.button decorator, and that you should create a button manually. So I added this code before the slash command and after the subclass of view:

```
supportServerButton = Button(label='Support Server', style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, url='https://discord.com')
helpView().add_item(supportServerButton)
```

However, I get this error:

```
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try creating an asyncio loop?

Comment: I didn't, but should I? If I should, how should I go about it?

Comment: Where are you importing `Button` from? Are you using `discord_buttons`?

Comment: I'm importing it from discord.ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `__init__` to your class. This will run when the class is initialized for the first time. From there you can add the URL button type to your class by using `self`.

```
class helpView(View):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(timeout=None)

    supportServerButton = discord.ui.Button(label='Support Server', style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, url='https://discord.com')
    self.add_item(supportServerButton)

  @discord.ui.button(label='Commands', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
  async def command_callback(self, button, interaction):
    await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=commandEmbed, view=commandView())
```

Comment: Is it possible to choose the order of the buttons? (for example, if I want a button with a link to be at the very beginning)

Comment: Late response, but simply just use the add_item function in the order you want the buttons.